# Setting the right screen resolution for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, resolution, screen-sharing

Under "Screen resolution" in Ubuntu, I don't have my screen's native resolution (SyncMaster 226BW).

What's the right way to make Ubuntu detect it?

Udi

Comment: Depending on your video card driver, check this out: http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=88429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not detecting the right resolution it may be that you need to install the drivers for your display device, if possible. This is most often an issue when using DVI monitors. Your also going to want to make sure your graphics card drivers are up to date as well.

If you have an Nvidia graphics card there's a great tutorial [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/nvidia) on getting the right drivers installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I have Googled it and found very little (perhaps I wasn't searching for the right terms).

Comment: See update for updating graphics card drivers